# User interactive Drawings

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, drawing, cad

I want to draw at my winforms application some CAD drawings.
Also I will need some parts of the drawings from them be a user interactive (Interactive with the mouse) .

Any idea what technology should i use for drawings here ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the opendwg library's for reading and writing cad files

http://www.opendwg.org/The_ODA_Platform

for .net

http://www.opendwg.org/the_oda_platform/dwgdirect.net

--

can't imagine building an full feature rich editor is going to be a simple task however.

good luck.